# Как сделать этот код через switch case?

Tags: java, android, if, switch, case

Помогите сделать это через `switch` `case`:

```
if (tint < 100) {
    //действия
} else if (tint < 200) {
    //действия
} else if (tint < 500) {
    //действия
}
```

Comment: а чем вам этот вариант не подходит?)

Comment: `switch(t/100): case 0: (t < 100) case 1: (t < 200)  case 2: case 3 case 4: (t<500)`

Comment: @tym32167 а case 2,3,4 надо или можно выкинуть?

Comment: зачем бы я это писал, если это можно было бы выкинуть :) Конечно надо.

Comment: сделать можно только длинно получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать это

```
switch(t/100) {
  case 0:
    //действия t<100
    break;
  case 1:
    //действия t<200
    break;
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
    //действия t<500
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

В данном случае в блок `default` попадут не только значения больше `500`, но и меньше `0`.

Comment: Ну что сказать, удобне через if :)

Comment: Про default я знаю. Кстати если кому-то интересно, я этот вопрос задал потому что в vb .Net можно писать case < 100. Вобщем всем спасибо)))

Comment: Кстати на счет break. Есть ли разница если его ставить/не ставить в конце действий каждого case?

Comment: @edcft в c# тоже есть [case when](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions), но java это более консервативный язык

Comment: @edcft да, есть разница. Подробнее [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), `The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)))

Comment: Сумбурное решение, больше похоже на г...код

Comment: @Arch это даже не решение. Автор спросил как ему переписать код на switch\case, я переписал, автор сравнил свой код и этот и выбрал, что ему больше подходит. По сути полезность этого ответа - это показать, что switch\case не подходит под задачу автора.